# Firebase Auth UserCredential - refers to a value, but is being used as a type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, types, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase, including auth, inside my React app with Typescript. So this is in a .tsx file

imported like `import UserCredential from 'firebase/auth'`

I am trying to apply the type [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#user-credential) to my function argument, like this

`const myCallback = (result: UserCredential) => { //function contents }`

but I am getting the error "*'UserCredential' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here"*

However, when I inspect the type-definitions for UserCredential, it is defined as a type. How can it "refer to a value" but clearly be a type? I'd like to be able to use it to type my function argument for the intellisense and consistency, etc. I'm sure there is something I'm missing -so this issue will probably keep coming up unless I can figure out what is wrong. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `firebase.User` solved my problem

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'

const myCallback = (result: firebase.User) => {
  // function contents
}
```

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I figured it out. I had to import it and use it like this,

`import { auth } from 'firebase';`

`const myCallback = (result: auth.UserCredential) => { //function contents }`

you could also import just firebase and consume firebase.auth.UserCredential

Answer (score 0):

The following worked (I'm using the [Compat firebase library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#about_the_compat_libraries)):

```js
// import
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";

// use
userCredential: firebase.auth.UserCredential
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but what worked for me is:

```
import { type UserCredential } from 'firebase/auth';
```